# Database with ListActivity

Tags: android

I am making my first programm to work with SQLite thath just one part of my program while i was extedning my class with Activity it was ok (form was sucesfully opened).

```
public class Obvestila extends ListActivity
```

Now i had to extend ListActivity instead of Activity. But now when i click on icon in menu to open this new form it crash. In logcat i dont see any detailed errors.

```
package com.test.testt;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Obvestila extends ListActivity{
    private CommentsDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
        Comment comment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            String[] comments = new String[] { "Cool", "Very nice", "Hate it" };
            int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);          
            comment = datasource.createComment(comments[nextInt]);
            adapter.add(comment);
            break;
        case R.id.delete:
            if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                comment = (Comment) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
                datasource.deleteComment(comment);
                adapter.remove(comment);
            }
            break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: if you have any error ,Always put full logcat here,,,,dont forget in future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your main.xml

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Oh my god :D I was loading false xml ^^. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no android.R.id.list element in your XML file. You ListView must have the following id in xml:

```
@android:id/list
```